# JPA, custom query and dates

Tags: java, datetime, jpa

I'm facing a strange issue. I've search including here in stack overflow and for JPA and Custom query I should specified the parameter. So I have a query string since I have over 14 fields but I'm facing issues with the dates. I'm always getting the IllegalStateException

```
INFO: query STRING = SELECT t FROM Tickets t  WHERE t.startdate > :startDate AND t.enddate < :endDate ORDER BY t.status DESC
WARNING: #{ticketController.search}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument startDate not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
```

as for my query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(query).setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
```

Although I'm getting that the parameter is not found, I have it in the setParameter and also set in the query as seen in the INFO line.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
INFO: query STRING = SELECT t FROM Tickets t  WHERE t.startdate > ?1 AND t.enddate < ?2 ORDER BY t.status DESC
WARNING: #{ticketController.search}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument 1 not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.

q = em.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).setParameter(2, endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Also and as advised, I've checked that the Date I'm using is java.util.Date. and in the entity class I have as Timestamp. But still I cannot have this working and not sure where I am failing.

Just to make sure that all the things are as they should, I forced the query to be string and I got the correct Exception:

```
INFO: query STRING = SELECT t FROM Tickets t  WHERE t.startdate > :startDate AND t.enddate < :endDate ORDER BY t.status DESC
WARNING: #{ticketController.search}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter startDate with expected type of class java.util.Date
```

But then again, I change to date and it fails :S
I've checked the reasons for this IllegalStateException:

And from the debug and from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) I get the following:
getResultList

**IllegalStateException - if called for a Java Persistence query language UPDATE or DELETE statement.**

I'm not doing a update nor delete :/

EDIT 2: Adding the Entity relevant part:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "startdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startdate;
@Column(name = "enddate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date enddate;
```

AS for the database creating script the columns are being created like this:

```
  startdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  endate timestamp with time zone,
```

If I do a normal SQL query like:
"select * from tbl_tickets where startdate > '2012-02-01 00:00:00' and enddate < '2013-03-18 23:59:50'"

I get the desired results. I guess I could do with native query but that would be going around the problem and not fixing this issue, right?

**EDIT 3:** Although I had everything set up properly, the init of the bean was calling again the query without the args ( sorry and thank you all for your help. It helped me checking what was amiss)

Comment: `endate` is in SQL is a typo, right?  Should be `enddate`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

javadoc for both

```
setParameter(String name, java.util.Date value, TemporalType temporalType)`
setParameter(String name, java.util.Calendar value, TemporalType temporalType)`
```

states:

> Throws: `IllegalArgumentException` - if the parameter name does not correspond to a parameter of the query or if the value argument is of incorrect type

Since you didn't provide full code, verify that:

- Java value `startDate` is of type `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`.
- SQL column `startDate` has valid SQL date type `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: thanks I updated the question, after validating not problem. I should also mention that when a record is created in the database, the startdate is automatically set by the application with a object of type date. and it saves correctly without error.

Comment: You're really leaving everyone guessing.  Please show: a) SQL used to create the table, and b) relevant portions of the Java Entity.

Comment: One piece still missing in your code - the variables & code that setup the query.  How are those variables declared?  They must be java Date or Calendar, right?

Comment: Accepting mostly because the above comment actually help me find my problem and resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
String query = "SELECT t FROM Tickets t  WHERE t.startdate > ?1 AND t.enddate < ?2 ORDER BY t.status DESC";
```

`Query q = em.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).setParameter(2, endDate, TemporalType.DATE);`

Answer (score 1):

I think that there should be a space between **:**(colon) and startDate in between. May be it is considering **:startDate** as a single word. Try this once

Answer (score 0):

```
Query q = em.createQuery(query).setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
```

If you carefully look at the [`setParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.util.Date,%20javax.persistence.TemporalType%29) you're using, it says that this `setParameter` requires a `Positional Parameter`, whereas, seeing your query, it seems you've used `Named Parameter`.

Hence, the `IllegalStateException`. Either change your query to provide `Positional Parameters`, or the `setParameter` to provide `Named Parameters` as input.

This is how you provide `Positional Parameter` in the query.

```
String query = "SELECT t FROM Tickets t  WHERE t.startdate > ?1 AND t.enddate < ?2 ORDER BY t.status DESC";
....
Query q = em.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).setParameter(2, endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I've tried as you mentioned but still same issue. And I only get this when q.getResultList is called. until then the variables are properly filled although in the debug mode I see the jpql query being marker as "startdate > ?" 
And thanks a lot for the explanation, I would have missed it for a long the named vs positional.

Comment: it says `IllegalArgumentException` now, which means either the local variable `startDate` is not `Date` type. That seems to be the only likely case.

Comment: that was to show that the line was actually being executed. I done it for testing when forcing the type to be string. I still get the state exception.

Comment: Hm.. there is also a setParameter method for setting a named parameter, and I think the code in question description uses it: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar,%20javax.persistence.TemporalType)